Are there natural deduction inference rules for function symbols?
This set of notes on natural deduction does not have rules of inference for function symbol. Is that supposed to be the case, or are the notes dealing with first-order logic without function symbols?

Please elaborate. What rules of inference are you talking about?

No, onlt the rules for equality. If we are dealing with a specific mathematical theory, like Peano arithmetic, we have rules for sum and product.

For the purposes of writing mathematical proofs, if you want to formally specify that $f$ is an arbitrary function mapping the elements of set $A$ to to those of set $B$, you can write: $\forall x\in A: f(x)\in B$.

... This notation neatly captures the uniqueness of images under $f$ since we have: $~~~~~~\forall x, y, z: [x\in A \land y\in B \land z\in B \implies [f(x)=y \land f(x)=z \implies y=z]]$.

The equality rules use terms: $s,t,u,\ldots$.
Obviously, terms can be built up from function symbols, like e.g. $s(0)$ and $x+y$ in first-order arithmetic, but there are no general rules dedicated specifically to function symbols.
But if we want to develop an axiomatic theory in "natural deduction form", we can easily write axioms ar rules, like e.g. the axiom for strict partial order where we need a specific rule for the $\lt$ relation (a binary predicate): $$\frac{a < b \ \ \ \ b < c}{ a < c}(\text {Tr})$$
Similarly, for First-order arithmetic, we can formalize axioms for the function symbols: successor, sum and product. See also here.
The recursion rules for sum will be:
$$\frac{}{ x+0 = x}(+ \text {Rec} 0)$$
and
$$\frac{}{ x+s(y) = s(x+y)}(+ \text {Rec} s)$$

The linked set of notes is explicitly advertised as being intended to be used alongside The Logic Manual by Volker Halbach.
The version of first-order logic in The Logic Manual (a very short book written for Oxford undergrads in philosophy) does not have function symbols in the formal language, as you guessed. [Or at least, not in the edition I have seen.]
Thinking through if/how/where/why we need to augment the Manual's ND system's rules to cover a language with function symbols is a useful exercise. We now have new sorts of terms available which can contain free variables: does the presence of such terms change the way we need to state the quantifier rules? If so, why? If not, why not?

Sorry, but doesn't your answer contradict Tankut's (correct me if I'm wrong)?

No contradiction was intended -- it was supposed to be an invitation to think things  through (and check one's working against some standard text!). But yes, it was unclear, sorry, so edited!

There are two main categories as to the inferential unit of logical systems:

Term-based systems.
Sentence-based systems.

Terms are represented with individual variables, constants and term-forming functions in the usual definition of the formal language associated with a logical system.
A typical example of term-based systems is the Aristotelian syllogism.
Propositional calculus and first-order predicate logic are the familiar systems for the sentence-based systems.
It should be remarked that, especially with the advent of computer science and linguistics, a plethora of systems have flourished which blur the mentioned categorical division.
To illustrate the difference in the view of terms, let us consider the introduction and elimination rules for equality in the Gentzen-style natural deduction (the other properties of equality can be derived from this pair of rules). The introduction rule for equality tells that any term $t$ is equal to itself and no premiss is required to conclude this:
$$\dfrac{}{t=t}\tag{=-introduction}$$
The elimination rule tells, in case that the terms $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$ are free for any variable $x$ occurring in $\phi(x)$, the term $t_{1}$ can be replaced by $t_{2}$:
$$\dfrac{t_{1}=t_{2}\qquad\phi(t_{1}/x)}{\phi(t_{2}/x)}\tag{=-elimination}$$
Note that equality is a logical predicate and the terms are not treated individually, but within a formula (n.b. $t=t$ is an atomic formula).
When a term is obtained with a term-forming function $f(t_{1},\ldots,t_{n})$ it takes on the same status as any variable or constant in quantifier and equality introduction and elimination rules.

For what it is worth, I use function symbols in my formal system which is based on how I believe logic is actually used in mathematical proofs. In that system, you can quantify on function symbols as on any free variable.
Example
$\forall f, g, X, Y, Z: [[\forall a \in X: f(a)\in Y] ~\land~ [\forall a\in Y: g(a) \in Z]$
$~~~\implies \forall a\in X: \exists b\in Z: g(f(a))=b]$
The first line introduces functions $f$ and $g$ and sets $X, Y$ and $Z$.
The second line introduces the composition of those functions.
